# Why does this keep printing out 51?

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(digitofPi(0));
    }
    public static int digitofPi(int digit)
    {
        String x = String.valueOf(Math.PI);
        char result = x.charAt(digit);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print out nth position of pi by converting pi to string, however it keeps printing out 51.

Comment: You got the bit about converting the number to a string, but you kinda forgot the bit about going back the other way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take your code step by step and let's consider that Pi = 3.1415

```
Math.PI = 3.1415
```

So, when you're

```
String x = String.valueOf(Math.PI);
```

Then

```
x = "3.1415"
```

And when you do this:

```
char result = x.charAt(digit);
```

Then `result` becomes `'3'`

And if you return an `int` from a `char`, it's going to take its ASCII value, so:

```
'3' = 51
```

So you can either return `char` or `String` on your method

```
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to return a `char`, not an `int`, unless you want to display the ASCII character code of the digit.

```
public static char digitofPi(int digit) {
    String x = String.valueOf(Math.PI);
    char result = x.charAt(digit);
    return result;
}
```

Note that you should remove the decimal point from the `String` if you do not want it to be treated as the second digit.

```
String x = String.valueOf(Math.PI).replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the character to int, which means you're getting it's ASCII code. (Actually Unicode codepoint, but for your case it's the same.)

http://www.asciitable.com/

If you look at it, you'll see that the code of "0" is 48 and the code of "3" is 53. So you'd have to subtract 48 from it.

Answer (score -2):

This one will return 51

```
public static int digitofPi(int digit) {
    String x = String.valueOf(Math.PI);
    return x.charAt(digit);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is the answer to *what question*?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question.  The OP is confused why their program is printing out `51`, I presume they would like it to print out `3`.